# PHP - Fetching an Object from a Custom Class using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

So I am new to PHP and particularly the world of PDO.
I am using PDO to select some data from a table and create an object out of this data. I have been successful with PDO creating a default object and accessing the results. This is the fetch statement for fetching a default object, which works as expected:

```
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

The next thing I want to do is fetch the results and create a custom object out of a predefined class that I have created. I based the below statement on what I was using for the first statement, however, this does not work

```
$stmt->execute();
$user_object = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_CLASS | PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE, 'classname');
```

I have got it working by setting the fetch mode outside of the fetch method and can be seen here:

```
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS| PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE,'classname');
$object = $stmt->fetch();
```

I have consulted the PHP manuals but I do not understand why I cannot have a statement like the second one i.e. set the fetchmode within the fetch statement.

Thanks

**Update**

The following statement:

```
$user_object = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_CLASS | PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE, 'classname');
var_dump($stmt->errorInfo());
var_dump($user_object);
```

Returns -

```
array(3) { [0]=> string(5) "00000" [1]=> NULL [2]=> NULL } bool(false)
```

Comment: It might be helpful to elaborate on the statement *this does not work*. E.g. Did you get an error? Did `fetch()` return `false`? Or did it return an object but not as expected?

Comment: Apologies no error was thrown, but when I use `var_dump($object)` it returns a `bool(false)` indicating that my object hasn't been created

Comment: And did the PDO `errorInfo()` method shed any light?

Comment: BTW, editing your question to include these additional details will be helpful, plus attract some new attention to the question as it will show up as recently modified in tag feeds.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this sample of code:

```
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
$sql = 'SELECT m.id, p.id_product productId, m.margin oldPrice
        FROM prefix_product p
        LEFT JOIN margin m
        ON p.id_product=m.product_id
        WHERE p.id_product=1
        ';
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, Class::class);
return $stmt->fetch();
```

It returns the Class object initialized with the columns names

Comment: Why don't you mention it's Doctrine and therefore unusable with vanilla PDO?

Comment: In my case the entity I want to update is not updatable directly with doctrine. That's why I have to create a custom request. But I can retrieve the connection directly with Doctrine. I just get the connection with doctrine but all the following code is like using PDO directly

Comment: But don't you understand that you are writing the answer not for your self, but for someone else? Who don't likely have neither $this->getEntityManager() nor FetchMode::CUSTOM_OBJECT?

Comment: I updated the code and get the conn with PDO.

Comment: With FetchMode::CUSTOM_OBJECT still in place.

Comment: Right, updated ;)